# Wait for a window message for a defined time

Tags: windows, winapi, loops, timer, window

I am programming with winapi. How do I wait for a message for a defined time?
If there is no message, I can do another task. I can not use Sleep, because the window callback procedure will be delayed.

```
while (true){
    ...//wait a message for 30 miliseconds
    GetMessage(&message, hwnd, 0, 0) ) or PeekMessage(&message, hwnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)
    ...
    if ( no_message ){
        call_a_function();
    } else {
        if (finish)
            break;
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
        ...//set to wait 30 minus elapsed time 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [timer](http://www.suite101.com/content/using-the-win32-timer-api-a23678).

[This site](http://www.suite101.com/content/win32-timer-callback-function-a23680) also shows how to use a win32 timer.

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly what [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684242%28VS.85%29.aspx) is for.

Comment: This function does not wait for window events.

Comment: Yes it does. See the dwWaitMask argument for the types of events it can wake up on.

Comment: This function fails and GetLastError() returns ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. I tried 
MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, (HANDLE*)&hwnd, true, 30, QS_ALLEVENTS ); 
MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &current_thread, true, 30, QS_ALLEVENTS );

Comment: The two things you tried are not valid HANDLE values. (HWNDs are not HANDLEs, nor are pointers to variables.) If you don't want to wait on a handle (e.g. an event or something), pass zero,NULL,FALSE for the first three args: e.g. MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, NULL, FALSE, 30, QS_ALLEVENTS)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an odd request.  Windows programs should be responsive.  If call_a_function takes any serious amount of time then your app will get the "This Windows is not responding" treatment.

Also, GetMessage goes into a wait state if there are no posted messages in the queue.  I don't understand why your message loop looks so different from the [canonical message loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644928%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#creating_loop).

I think to answer this question well it would be helpful to know the purpose of your call_a_function routine.